# Create WPF-MahApps.Metro Animated tab control to MetroWindow title bar

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

Can we able to create a [MahApps Metro Master](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/) Animated Tab Control on to Metro Window title bar ?

I wrote a code like,

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.WindowCommands>
    <Controls:WindowCommands HorizontalAlignment="Left">

        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items1}" FontWeight="Thin" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Rectangle Width="20" Height="10">
                                    <Rectangle.Resources>
                                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlackBrush" Color="White"/>
                                    </Rectangle.Resources>
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <!--<VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_cupcake}" />-->
                                        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Resources/Images/menu-home-off.png"></ImageBrush>
                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                </Rectangle>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Margin="100 100 100 100" Content="{Binding Content}" Foreground="White" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>

    </Controls:WindowCommands>
</Controls:MetroWindow.WindowCommands>
```

The Tab `ItemTemplate` is displaying in Title Window, The `ContentTemplate` is not displaying....

Is it possible?
If yes, How can i achieve this ?

Thanks in advance !!